# How to check if the variable in date is more then 10 seconds older than the current date

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

I have some method that downloads data from the internet (let's call it updater) and because a few different other methods use this `updater()`, I don't want to overcrowd the server with queries.

I did it like this: a private variable of the result of `updater()` and a private variable of `lastUpdate` (`Date` type), that tells me (using `Calendar` class) when the last query was held.

Now, when the query was in last 10 seconds, I want to just return the old result.

The problem is: I don't know how to get information wheter 10 seconds have passed from `actualDate` and `lastUpdate`. In the `Date` class, there are only methods for `after(Date d)`, `before(Date d)` or `equals(Object o)`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you drop `Date` because most of it is deprecated. Instead use `Calendar` (or an external library like [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)) for your date functionality.

Another possibility is to just use the current date + time in milliseconds. It's very easy to use and you can easily transform it to a `Calendar` using `setTimeInMillis()`.

A sample could be like this:

```
private long lastTime = 0;

if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastTime + 10000) {
    // Perform action
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the current date is the first option. the .getTime() method returns the time in milliseconds, so comparing them, 10 seconds is a value of more than 10000

```
if (actualDate.getTime()-lastUpdate.getTime() >10000) {
  // more than 10 seconds have passed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct.

But you should learn to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or, in Java 8, the new JSR 310 java.time.* classes. The old java.util.Date/Calendar classes are notoriously bad.

Here's some example code in Joda-Time 2.3 to get you going.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime lastChecked = new DateTime();

// …
try {
    System.out.println( "Sleeping. lastChecked: " + lastChecked );
    Thread.sleep( 12 * 1000 );  // Milliseconds.
} catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if ( DateTime.now().isAfter( lastChecked.plusSeconds( 10 ) )) {
    // Update
    System.out.println( "Updating." );
} else {
    // Wait.
    System.out.println( "Waiting." );
}
```

Resources:

- [Pausing execution with Sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)
- Static method [`now()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#now%28%29) on [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), alternative to `new DateTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.getTime();
```

This gives the epoch time as in the time in millisec since Jan 1970. You can convert your date to time in milleseconds and compare the difference to check if it older than 10 seconds.